# How should I fix this?

Tags: java, binary

When I run the program and it asks me to input a number between 0 to 511. I enter 7 it turns out to be

TTT
TTT
TTT

but it should be like this
HHH
HHH
TTT

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class coins {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 511");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        int[] result = decimalToBinary(number);
        displayHeadAndTails(result);
    }
    public static int[] decimalToBinary(int number) {
        int[] result = new int[9];
        int i = result.length - 1;
        while (number != 0) {
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                result[i--] = '0';
            } else {
                result[i--] = '1';
            }
            number /= 2;
        }
        for (int k = i; k >= 0; k--) {
            result[k] = '0';
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void displayHeadAndTails(int[] result) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (result[i] == 0)
                System.out.print("H");
            else System.out.print("T");
            if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the values in result. `'0'` is not the same thing as `0`

Answer (score 2):

Change `result[i] == 0` to `result[i] == '0'` and it will work

```
public static void displayHeadAndTails(int[] result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (result[i] == '0')
            System.out.print("H");
        else System.out.print("T");
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Also,it's better to using `{}` after `if else`